# Upload files to bucket with <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader> CORS rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, cors

I use [ReactS3Uploader](https://github.com/odysseyscience/react-s3-uploader) to upload files from browswer to s3. My CORS rules are as followings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

If I change `<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>` to `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`, everyting works fine. But I have errors when I use `<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>`:

```
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Following is my ReactS3Uploader:

```
<ReactS3Uploader
              signingUrl="/s3/sign"
              signingUrlMethod="GET"
              //accept="image/*"
              s3path="/test"
              //signingUrlHeaders={{ additional: headers }}
              //signingUrlQueryParams={{ additional: query-params }}
              //signingUrlWithCredentials={ true }      // in case when need to pass authentication credentials via CORS
              uploadRequestHeaders={{ 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read' }}  // this is the default
              contentDisposition="auto"
              scrubFilename={(filename) => filename.replace(/[^\w\d_\-.]+/ig, '')}
              server="http://localhost:3001" />
```

Following is my server side code for the signature:

```
app.use('/s3', require('react-s3-uploader/s3router')({
    bucket: "bucktmodel",
    region: 'us-east-1', //optional
    signatureVersion: 'v2', //optional (use for some amazon regions: frankfurt and others)
    //headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}, // optional
    ACL: 'private', // this is default
    uniquePrefix: true // (4.0.2 and above) default is true, setting the attribute to false preserves the original filename in S3
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because:

1) I don't have permissions to upload files, so I need to add policy to enable upload to this bucket;

2) I have multiple space lines end the end of my CORS settings